# Error "EXC BAD ACCESS"with subclass in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made 3 files `GameViewController`, `GameView`, `GameItemView` but if `GameItemView` inherits `GameView` than

> EXC BAD ACCESS error appeared

like below code.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var gameView: GameView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        gameView = GameView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height:     568))
        self.view.addSubview(gameView)
        gameView.gameViewController = self

    }

//....

}

class GameView: UIView {

    weak var gameViewController: GameViewController! //when GameViewController will appear, BAD ACCESS error     appear and stop here

    weak var gameItemView: GameItemView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        gameItemView = GameItemView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,     height: 568))
        self.addSubview(gameItemView)
    }
    //....

}

class GameItemView: GameView {    

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        //add some views
    }
//...

}
```

I wrote some code of `GameItemView` on `GameView` before. But `GameView's` code became so long, so I moved a part of them to `GameItemView`. But then the error appeared. How can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**

I'll add the code where I got the error. I'm sorry I forgot to write it.

```
var gameGameViewController: GameViewController!
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and run the code. It would point to the line causing the crash. Then you can look into solving it

Comment: remove variable `gameItemView` from `GameView`. Or if you need that Then **DON'T inherit**  `GameView` into `GameItemView`

Comment: in which line you got this error?

Comment: The view shouldn't know in which viewcontroller it is in

Comment: @gowtham I updated the code. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you inheriting `GamveViewItem` from `GameView`? If you wanted to do so then why are coding like above which causes recursive calls to the `init` of `GamveViewItem` & `GameView`. Please either change the parent class of the `GamveViewItem` to `UIView` or some other or break the recursive pattern caused by the `init`.

`GameView`'s init

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // Here you're calling GameItemView's init, now go to GameItemView's init 
    gameItemView = GameItemView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 568))
    self.addSubview(gameItemView)
}
```

`GameItemView`'s init

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    // You're calling GameView's init here and it goes back to 
    // there and then this keep on happening
    super.init(frame: frame)

    //add some views
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var gameView: GameView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gameView = GameView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 568))
    self.view.addSubview(gameView)
    gameView.gameViewController = self

    }

     //....

}

class GameView: UIView {

var gameViewController = GameViewController()
var gameItemView = GameItemView()
override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame:frame)
   gameItemView = GameItemView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 568))
    self.addSubview(gameItemView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}

class GameItemView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //add some views
 }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used your code but if GameView and GameItemView call each other like "gameView.something()" and "gameItemView.something = true", deinit isn't called. I tried to use "weak   var gameItemView = GameItemView()" and if view will disappear gameView.gameItemView = nil, deinit isn't called....